# Search for particular words in frequency table

Tags: r

I've been struggling to search for specific words in my frequency table, containing a bunch of University and Company names. I'd like to split this table into 2 table (or list) of 1-"Universities" and 2-"Companies". To do this, I'm thinking of searching for specific words of "University" "School" "College", and writing them all into table (or list) called "Universities". The remainder of entries of the table (presumably "Company" names) will form the 2nd table (or list) named "Companies"

I looked into this and found grep("University", OriginalFrequencyTable) isn;t working. I suppose the reason is because grep works with a character vector and not a table(?!)

```
OriginalFrequencyTable: (number in front of names is frequency of occurrence)

Loyalist College 2 
Globe Inc 4
University Of Central Arkansas 3
Anderson University 2
Bridgewater State College 1
Allegheny College 1
Cs Technologies 3
Healthpartners 1

Expected result (are 2 tables named, "Universities" and "Companies"):

--------------1st table "Universities":--------------
Loyalist College 2 
University Of Central Arkansas 3
Anderson University 2
Bridgewater State College 1
Allegheny College 1

--------------2nd table "Companies":--------------
Globe Inc 4
Cs Technologies 3
Healthpartners 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated,
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I often find data frames allow for better data manipulation in R.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` to split the data.frame into a `list` of `data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
lst1 <- split(df, str_detect(df$Name, "\\b(College|University)\\b"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I'm dealing with a "frequency table". Could you elaborate a bit on how to go about filtering entries of such a table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Riccardo  Is it a `table` object?  Pls confirm by checking the `str(df)`

Comment: Yes, `CompanyUniversity <- df$Name` then I do ` table(CompanyUniversity)` giving a frequency table for all company and university names. Now I'd like to split this table into 2. One contaning ONLY company names, the other only university names (with frequency numbers shown for each name, as shown in output of table() command)

Comment: @Riccardo  Try `dat <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(CompanyUniversity))` and then do the `split`

Comment: I did that..It's saying: "Error in seq_len(ncols) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer"

Comment: @Riccardo It should have worked.  Can you update with the `dput` of a small example so that I can understand the issue better

Comment: Sure. I've run dput command and saved the output in a variable. Could you let me know how I may send it to you?

Comment: @Riccardo  When you do the `dput`, do it on a small example and then get the output and paste it on your post by editing it.

Comment: structure(list(country = structure(c(5L, 7L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("China", 
"Georgia", "Iraq", "Japan", "Korea, Republic of", "Philippines", 
"Taiwan", "United States"), class = "factor"), company..org = structure(c(7L, 
10L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Al-Maraj Co", "Au Net", 
"Cho University", "Computer Net Center", "Globe Mobile", 
"Magcom Ltd.", "Computing Info Service", 
"Princeton University", "Spectrum Business", "Taiwan Network", 
"Taiyuan University", "Troad Broadcast", 
"Johns Hopkins Institution", "Wuxi University"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I've included `dput()` output here for your review. Any advice is highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: @Riccardo if the `split` output is `lst1 <- split(df, str_detect(df$company..org, "\\b(College|University)\\b"))` what do you want to do from there?  The `dput` output  shows that is a data.frame

Comment: My apologies if this is naive query but once I issue the `lst1 <- split(DataFrame, str_detect(DataFrame$company..org, "\\b(College|University)\\b"))` you that you indicated above, R says:  could not find function "str_detect". Is str_detect a buitin function? Here is my R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)

Comment: @Riccardo It is from `stringr`.  Load the package `library(stringr)` and the error will not be gone

Comment: Many thanks. I've got the list of data.fame now, lst1 has 2 major components, FALSE and TRUE. I'm interested in FALSE as its company..org entry contains the list of "Companies" that I'm after. Now, I'd like to print the companies listed in FALSE > company..org as a column table on my plot using `text()`. (I have already a plot which is a visual display of relative frequency for all companies and universities..., and am thinking of adding a table which lists only the companies to make the plot more informative). Is there any way to extract company..org as table or csv?   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One base R option would be to use `grepl` and search for the keywords `College` or `University` as markers of a school:

```
Universities <- df[grepl("\\b(College|University)\\b", df$Name), ]
Companies <- df[!grepl("\\b(College|University)\\b", df$Name), ]
```

I am not sure what your column(s) is called, by I assumed there is a `Name` column containing the company and university names.  If there be an actual separate column for the frequency, then the above solution should still work.  It should also work if you have the name and frequency together in a single column.

Comment: Biegeleise. Many thanks for replying to my query. My apologies if I was not clear enough. I'm having a "frequency table" (please kindly see title of my post) and expecting 2 tables. I think your solution works just fine for a column containing University and Company names. To be more precise, I'm having `table(df$Name)`, which is the table you see in my initial post/problem description. What I expect is 2 tables filtered by keywords (as markers of a school), so I'm interested in is solely names of University and Company and with a frequency in front of the names, i.e. `table(df$Name)`.

Comment: My answer is already doing this, at least it was when I tested the code.  You just need to subset the original data frame to generate two new data frames.

Comment: Hi Tim, Many thanks for prompt reply. Here is my issue. Once I take your line of code `Companies <- df[!grepl("\\b(College|University)\\b", df$Name), ]` (which actually is a subset of the original dataframe), and do `table(Companies$Name)`, I get a frequency table of company names, however, there still exist University names, with "0" frequency. I'm just taking your code and issue `table()` command on you 2 new dataframes. Do you have any idea why this is happening. Appreciate your comments in advance.

Comment: Wait...are you saying that you want the names and frequencies as separate columns?  Is this is the issue?

Comment: I'd like to get two separate tables out of the original frequency table. One for "Companies", the other for "Universities. When I do you lines of code (which generate two subsets, called  Universities and Companies), and then run table() command on each subset, what I get is a frequency table (for each subset), where for Universities subset, I see frequency (number of occurrence, e.g. 2 3 1 ...) for University names, and "0" for company names.

Comment: Similarly, for the other subset "Companies", I see "0" (occurrance) for all University names and the actual frequency for all Companies. What I'm expecting to get is 2 frequency tables, one for subset "Universities" containing ONLY University names (with frequnecy shown as in you run table() command) and NO company names. and the other freq table for subset "Companies" containing only Company names (with no University names).     :)

Comment: ."are you saying that you want the names and frequencies as separate columns? Is this is the issue? " > No, just in need of two frequency tables, one having only Company names, the other table, with only University names.